# Prove that the linear mapping $f: V \to V'$ is injective if and only if $g: V' \to V$ exists such that $gf = 1_V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Prove that the linear mapping $f: V \to V'$ is injective if and only
>   if $g: V' \to V$ exists such that $gf = 1_V$

If $f$ is injective, $Kerf=0$, but I actually don't understand what $(1_V)$ means, I know - elementary knowledge. Because our mapping is mapped back into $V$?

Comment: $1_V$ is the function $V\longrightarrow V$ such that $1_V(v)=v$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: I think I finally see the whole problem. If $f$ isn't injective, then there exists some nonzero vector $v \in V$ such that $f(v) = 0$ and this vector can't be mapped back from $V'$ to $V$ as the same nonzero vector.?

Comment: That gives you one direction. Now you have to suppose $f$ is injective, and construct a linear map $g:V'\longrightarrow V$ such that $gf=1_V$. Hint: find a suitable basis for $V'$ and define $g$ on that basis.

Comment: So if I have a basis in $V$, for example $M= \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ and the basis in $W$, for example $N= \{w_1,w_2,...,w_n\}$ then if I want to map $v$ into $V'$ I can do it as $f(v_j) =\sum_{i=i}^n r_{ij}v_i = w_j$? And back $g(f(v_j)) =\sum_{i=i}^n r_{ij}f(v_i )=\sum_{i=i}^n r_{ij} w_j$... I got lost.

Comment: I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lets show both implications:

Suppose $f$ is injective, then $Ker(f)=\{0\}$ then you can construct $g$ as follows: Take $v'\in V'$ if there exists some $v'\in V'´´$ such that $f(v)=v'$ then $g(v')=v$ and the $v$ is unique due to injectivity, if there is no such $v'$ then $g(v')=0$ due to $Im(f)$ being a subspace we know that this g is linear and it's easy to see $gf(v)=1_V$ for every $v\in V$.

Now suppose there exists such $g$ and suppose that $f(v_1)=f(v_2)$ then we have that $f(v_1-v_2)=0$, now g must be linear so $g(0)=0$ but at the same time $g(f(v_1-v_2))=v_1-v_2$ and it implies $v_1-v_2$ must be $0$ and then $v_1=v_2$ so  f must be injective.

Answer (score 1):

You already showed in the comments that if $f$ is not injective then no such $g$ exists. So assume $f$ is injective. Let $M$ be a basis of $V$. Then since $f$ is injective, $f(M)$ is linearly independent in $V'$ (check this). Complete $f(M)$ to a basis $M'$ of $V'$. Define $g$ on $M'$ by saying $g(x)=y$ if $x\in f(M)$ and $x=f(y)$, and define $g(x)=0$ if $x\notin f(M)$. Then extend $g$ linearly. This gives the required left inverse.